# Ordering admin.ModelAdmin objects in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-apps, django-modeladmin

Let's say I have my pizza application with Topping and Pizza classes and they show in Django Admin like this:

```
PizzaApp
-
Toppings      >>>>>>>>>>      Add / Change

Pizzas        >>>>>>>>>>      Add / Change
```

But I want them like this:

```
PizzaApp
-
Pizzas        >>>>>>>>>>      Add / Change

Toppings      >>>>>>>>>>      Add / Change
```

How do I configure that in my `admin.py`?

Comment: I added it to Django's trac: [http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9928](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9928)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually covered at the very bottom of [Writing your first Django app, part 7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial07/).

Here's the relevant section:

> **Customize the admin index page**
>
> On a similar note, you might want to
>   customize the look and feel of the
>   Django admin index page.
>
> By default, it displays all the apps
>   in INSTALLED_APPS that have been
>   registered with the admin application,
>   in alphabetical order. You may want to
>   make significant changes to the
>   layout. After all, the index is
>   probably the most important page of
>   the admin, and it should be easy to
>   use.
>
> The template to customize is
>   admin/index.html. (Do the same as with
>   admin/base_site.html in the previous
>   section -- copy it from the default
>   directory to your custom template
>   directory.) Edit the file, and you'll
>   see it uses a template variable called
>   app_list. That variable contains every
>   installed Django app. Instead of using
>   that, you can hard-code links to
>   object-specific admin pages in
>   whatever way you think is best.

Comment: This is good to know, but I think the question related to a couple of Model classes in the same installed app.  Changing the order of the apps wouldn't help you if you wanted to change the order of your Model classes within a single app.

Comment: It's good thinking. They have to be listed somewhere and maybe I just have to apply a sorting filter there. I'm going to look at this tomorrow (European timezone here...) Thanks

Comment: I think the easy solution from 林伟雄 bellow is worth to try. Small addition into settings.py only.

Answer (score 49):

A workaround that you can try is tweaking your models.py as follows:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    .
    .
    .
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "2. Toppings"

class Pizza(models.Model):
    .
    .
    .
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "1. Pizzas"
```

Not sure if it is against the django's best practices but it works (tested with django trunk).

Good luck!

PS: sorry if this answer was posted too late but it can help others in future similar situations.

Comment: This is what I am using. Although a workaround, it is the simplest aproach.

Comment: sad. it would say "3 1. Pizzas" at last if you have 3 pizza entries.

Comment: Yes I mean "cool" workaound but seems ridicoulus Django didn't implement a better solution. Ordering by number would feel more obvious or even better the ORDER IN WHICH YOU REGISTER the model, in this way we are adding a number on a display name .. very weird.

Comment: In addition, if you need to place something in between, let's say you have 10 models and you need to place something at position 2, you have to manually switch all number 2 --> 10 adding it. very not cool .

Answer (score 33):

If you want to solve this in 10 seconds just use spaces in verbose_name_plural, for example:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "  Toppings" # 2 spaces

class Pizza(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = " Pizzas" # 1 space
```

Of course it isn't ellegant but may work for a while before we get a better solution.

Comment: Works in latest Django 1.11. Note that the spaces at the beginning are not rendered by the browser, so it doesn't have a visual impact in the title. Also note that this works with `AppConfig` classes, to re-order the applications sections too.

Comment: Super janky but definitely the quickest and dirtiest!

Comment: 10 years later, and *still, hands down* the fastest, easiest solution. Thanks!

Comment: The most beautiful method for Django 4.x

Answer (score 22):

I eventually managed to do it thanks to this [Django snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1939/#comments), you just need to be aware of the `ADMIN_REORDER` setting:

```
ADMIN_REORDER = (
    ('app1', ('App1Model1', 'App1Model2', 'App1Model3')),
    ('app2', ('App2Model1', 'App2Model2')),
)
```

`app1` must not be prefixed with the project name, i.e. use `app1` instead of `mysite.app1`.

Comment: Well, this worked on version 1.3, what is the problem you're facing ?

Comment: What may not be clear is that you need the whole snippet, not just the code block posted in this answer.

Comment: Inspired by the snippet I wrote 
https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder

Comment: @mishbah would you please update it for Django 2.x or any reference link on how to do for inner pages?

Answer (score 19):

There's now a nice Django package for that:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-modeladmin-reorder

Answer (score 18):

Answer in June 2018

This answer is similar to [Vasil's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1140868/9963540)

I tried to solve similar problems, and then I saw such [the fragment](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/set_ordering.html).

I made some modifications based on this clip. The code is as follows.

```
# myproject/setting.py
...
# set my ordering list
ADMIN_ORDERING = [
    ('pizza_app', [
        'Pizzas',
        'Toppings'
    ]),
]
# Creating a sort function
def get_app_list(self, request):
    app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)
    for app_name, object_list in ADMIN_ORDERING:
        app = app_dict[app_name]
        app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: object_list.index(x['object_name']))
        yield app


# Covering django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.get_app_list
from django.contrib import admin

admin.AdminSite.get_app_list = get_app_list
...
```

**Note that the sorting list used in this sorting function contains the sorting of all app and its modules in the system. If you don't need it, please design the sorting function according to your own needs.**

It works great on Django 2.0

Comment: If there is a plan to optimize this code or other implementations, please generously share it with me. Thank you！

Comment: This returned a ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) when I tried to do this. Django 2.1 here.

Comment: I don't know the Error from where, Could you show me your exception stack?@Nathan

Comment: i actually wrote my own script to take care of this. I wrote about it here: https://zhuzhu-limited.com/django-admin-app-and-model-reordering/

Comment: This is the simplest and more elegant solution out there! Well done.

Comment: This is cool. Works perfectly fine on Django 2.2 with the default Django Admin. All the changes are in `settings.py`, no need to edit templates, which is required in most other solutions.

Comment: Great ! Works with 3.1. I have added following after your yield command:    `explicit_app_names = [app_name for app_name, object_list in ADMIN_ORDERING]
    for app_name in app_dict:
        if app_name not in explicit_app_names:
            yield app_dict[app_name]`
So I have everything in admin and can reorder only those apps which are important for me. Such explicitly defined apps are then on top, but I think such behaviour is not bad.

Comment: @Nathan I'm sorry it took so long to see the news. The link you provided can't be accessed. I don't know if your problem is solved. I guess this problem is caused by the python version,
You can try the following modifications:                     
-  for app_ name, object_ list in ADMIN_ ORDERING:           
+ for app_ name, object_ list in ADMIN_ ORDERING.items():

Comment: A less hacky solution is to provide a custom AdminSite in which you override get_app_list().

Answer (score 5):

Here's the snippet Emmanuel used, updated for Django 1.8:

In templatetags/admin_reorder.py:

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings
from collections import OrderedDict

register = template.Library()

# from http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1937/
def register_render_tag(renderer):
    """
    Decorator that creates a template tag using the given renderer as the 
    render function for the template tag node - the render function takes two 
    arguments - the template context and the tag token
    """
    def tag(parser, token):
        class TagNode(template.Node):
            def render(self, context):
                return renderer(context, token)
        return TagNode()
    for copy_attr in ("__dict__", "__doc__", "__name__"):
        setattr(tag, copy_attr, getattr(renderer, copy_attr))
    return register.tag(tag)

@register_render_tag
def admin_reorder(context, token):
    """
    Called in admin/base_site.html template override and applies custom ordering
    of apps/models defined by settings.ADMIN_REORDER
    """
    # sort key function - use index of item in order if exists, otherwise item
    sort = lambda order, item: (order.index(item), "") if item in order else (
        len(order), item)
    if "app_list" in context:
        # sort the app list
        order = OrderedDict(settings.ADMIN_REORDER)
        context["app_list"].sort(key=lambda app: sort(order.keys(),
            app["app_url"].strip("/").split("/")[-1]))
        for i, app in enumerate(context["app_list"]):
            # sort the model list for each app
            app_name = app["app_url"].strip("/").split("/")[-1]
            if not app_name:
                app_name = app["name"].lower()
            model_order = [m.lower() for m in order.get(app_name, [])]
            context["app_list"][i]["models"].sort(key=lambda model:
            sort(model_order, model["admin_url"].strip("/").split("/")[-1]))
    return ""
```

In settings.py:

```
ADMIN_REORDER = (
    ('app1', ('App1Model1', 'App1Model2', 'App1Model3')),
    ('app2', ('App2Model1', 'App2Model2')),
)
```

(insert your own app names in here. Admin will place missing apps or models at the end of the list, so long as you list at least two models in each app.)

In your copy of base_site.html:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_reorder %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Django site admin' %}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
{% admin_reorder %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'Django administration' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using [Suit](http://djangosuit.com) for the AdminSite you can do menu customization using the [menu tag](http://django-suit.readthedocs.org/en/develop/configuration.html#id1).

Comment: Using the menu tag, I succeeded only in changing the left menu appearance.

Answer (score 3):

```
ADMIN_ORDERING = {
    "PizzaApp": [
        "Pizzas",
        "Toppings",
    ],
}


def get_app_list(self, request):
    app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)
    for app_name, object_list in app_dict.items():
        if app_name in ADMIN_ORDERING:
            app = app_dict[app_name]
            app["models"].sort(
                key=lambda x: ADMIN_ORDERING[app_name].index(x["object_name"])
            )
            app_dict[app_name]
            yield app
        else:
            yield app_dict[app_name]


admin.AdminSite.get_app_list = get_app_list
```

This solution works for me, modified the one from 林伟雄.

You get to keep the default auth ordering AND specify your own.

Answer (score 3):

You can reorder and hide the apps and models in admin pages. *I use **Django 4.1.7**.

For example, there are the same 3 models in `app1/models.py` and `app2/models.py` as shown below:

```py
# "app1/models.py
# "app2/models.py

from django.db import models

class Model1(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Model1'

class Model2(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Model2'

class Model3(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Model3'
```

Then, there are the same 3 admins in `app1/admin.py` and `app2/admin.py` as shown below:

```py
# "app1/admin.py
# "app2/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Model1, Model2, Model3

@admin.register(Model1)
class Model1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(Model2)
class Model2Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(Model3)
class Model3Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Then, 3 apps including `AUTHENTICATION AND AUTHORIZATION(auth)` are displayed in `Home` admin page as shown below:

[image]

Now, set `ADMIN_ORDERING` and treat it in overridden `get_app_list()` in `settings.py` as shown below. *You can see the original [get_app_list()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c914d6cff176ae6bfab2f33a84bcfd45208f1894/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L533) in GitHub:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

ADMIN_ORDERING = (
    ('app2', (
        'Model3', 
        'Model1', 
        'Model2'
    )),
    ('auth', (
        'User', 
        'Group'
    )),
    ('app1', (
        'Model2', 
        'Model3', 
        'Model1'
    ))
)

from django.contrib import admin

def get_app_list(self, request, app_label=None):
    app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request, app_label)
    
    if not app_dict:
        return
        
    NEW_ADMIN_ORDERING = []
    if app_label:
        for ao in ADMIN_ORDERING:
            if ao[0] == app_label:
                NEW_ADMIN_ORDERING.append(ao)
                break
    
    if not app_label:
        for app_key in list(app_dict.keys()):
            if not any(app_key in ao_app for ao_app in ADMIN_ORDERING):
                app_dict.pop(app_key)
    
    app_list = sorted(
        app_dict.values(), 
        key=lambda x: [ao[0] for ao in ADMIN_ORDERING].index(x['app_label'])
    )
     
    for app, ao in zip(app_list, NEW_ADMIN_ORDERING or ADMIN_ORDERING):
        if app['app_label'] == ao[0]:
            for model in list(app['models']):
                if not model['object_name'] in ao[1]:
                    app['models'].remove(model)
        app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: ao[1].index(x['object_name']))
    return app_list

admin.AdminSite.get_app_list = get_app_list
```

Then, the order of 3 apps and the models is changed in `Home` admin page as shown below. *The order of them is also changed in other admin pages not just in `Home` admin page:

[image]

Next, remove `Model1` in `app2`, `auth` itself and all models in `app1` to hide them as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

ADMIN_ORDERING = (
    ('app2', (
        'Model3', 
        # 'Model1', 
        'Model2'
    )),
    # ('auth', (
    #     'User', 
    #     'Group'
    # )),
    ('app1', (
        # 'Model2', 
        # 'Model3', 
        # 'Model1'
    ))
)

# ...
```

Then, `Model1` in `app2`, `auth` itself and all models in `app1` are hidden in `Home` admin page as shown below. *They are also hidden in other admin pages not just in `Home` admin page:

[image]

In addition, even if the apps and models which don't exist are set to `ADMIN_ORDERING` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

ADMIN_ORDERING = (
    ('app2', (
        'Model3', 
        'Model1', 
        'Model2',
        'Model4', # Doesn't exist
        'Model5'  # Doesn't exist
    )),
    ('auth', (
        'Model1', # Doesn't exist
        'User', 
        'Group',
        'Model2'  # Doesn't exist
    )),
    ('app1', ( 
        'Group',  # Doesn't exist
        'Model2', 
        'Model3', 
        'Model1',
        'User'    # Doesn't exist
    )),
    ('app3', ( # Doesn't exist
        'Model1', # Doesn't exist
        'Model2', # Doesn't exist
        'Model3'  # Doesn't exist
    ))
)

# ...
```

Then, they are ignored and not displayed as shown below. Actually, I wanted to return error if the apps and models which don't exist are set to `ADMIN_ORDERING` but I don't have much time to think about it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a simple solution where I could order the apps by their name in the admin panel. I came up with the following template tag:

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def sort_apps(apps):
    apps.sort(
        key = lambda x:
        settings.APP_ORDER.index(x['app_label'])
        if x['app_label'] in settings.APP_ORDER
        else len(apps)
    )
    print [x['app_label'] for x in apps]
    return apps
```

Then, just override `templates/admin/index.html` and add that template tag:

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load i18n static sort_apps %}
<div id="content-main">

{% if app_list %}
    {% for app in app_list|sort_apps %}
        <div class="app-{{ app.app_label }} module">
        <table>
        <caption>
            <a href="{{ app.app_url }}" class="section" title="{% blocktrans with name=app.name %}Models in the {{ name }} application{% endblocktrans %}">{{ app.name }}</a>
        </caption>
        {% for model in app.models %}
            <tr class="model-{{ model.object_name|lower }}">
            {% if model.admin_url %}
                <th scope="row"><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}">{{ model.name }}</a></th>
            {% else %}
                <th scope="row">{{ model.name }}</th>
            {% endif %}

            {% if model.add_url %}
                <td><a href="{{ model.add_url }}" class="addlink">{% trans 'Add' %}</a></td>
            {% else %}
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            {% endif %}

            {% if model.admin_url %}
                <td><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}" class="changelink">{% trans 'Change' %}</a></td>
            {% else %}
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            {% endif %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>{% trans "You don't have permission to edit anything." %}</p>
{% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Then customized the `APP_ORDER` in settings.py:

```
APP_ORDER = [
    'app1',
    'app2',
    # and so on...
]
```

It works great on Django 1.10

Comment: Yep, nice work in Django 2.0. For initialize you can using `libraries` key in `TEMPLATES['OPTIONS']` dict like that:
```
'libraries': {
                'sort_apps': 'src.apps.utils.templatetags.customize_tags',
            }
```
Without adding to INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @teror4uks would you please explain it a little more

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that gives you a bit more flexibility, namely:

- You can partially define apps ordering, leaving the rest for Django to add to the list
- You can specify order on modules, or avoid defining it, by using '*' instead
- Your defined apps ordering will appear first, then all the rest of apps appended after it
- To check the name of your app, either look at the file `apps.py` inside the app's directory and check for name property of the `class Config(AppConfi):` or in case that is not present, use the name of the directory for the app in the project.

Add this code somewhere in your `settings.py` file:

```py
# ======[Setting the order in which the apps/modules show up listed on Admin]========
# set my ordering list
ADMIN_ORDERING = [
    ('crm', '*'),
    ('property', '*'),
]


# Creating a sort function
def get_app_list(self, request):
    """
    Returns a sorted list of all the installed apps that have been
    registered in this site.

    Allows for:
        ADMIN_ORDERING = [
            ('app_1', [
                'module_1',
                'module_2'
            ]),
            ('app_2', '*'),
        ]
    """

    app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)

    # Let's start by sorting the apps alphabetically on a list:
    app_list = sorted(app_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x['name'].lower())

    # Sorting the models alphabetically within each app.
    for app in app_list:
        if app['app_label'] in [el[0] for el in ADMIN_ORDERING]:
            app_list.remove(app)
        else:
            app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])

    # Now we order the app list in our defined way in ADMIN_ORDERING (which could be a subset of all apps).
    my_ordered_apps = []
    if app_dict:
        for app_name, object_list in ADMIN_ORDERING:
            app = app_dict[app_name]
            if object_list == '*':
                app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])
            else:
                app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: object_list.index(x['object_name']))
            my_ordered_apps.append(app)

        # Now we combine and arrange the 2 lists together
        my_ordered_apps.extend(app_list)

    return my_ordered_apps

# Covering django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.get_app_list
from django.contrib import admin
admin.AdminSite.get_app_list = get_app_list
# =========================================
```

This is nothing more than overwriting the function defined by Django on the file python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py.

That `get_app_list` method of `class AdminSite(object):` produces a data structure with all apps on the project, including for Django's auth app, such as:

```
[
  {
    "app_label": "auth",
    "app_url": "/admin/auth/",
    "has_module_perms": "True",
    "models": [
      {
        "add_url": "/admin/auth/group/add/",
        "admin_url": "/admin/auth/group/",
        "name": "<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x11057f990>",
        "object_name": "Group",
        "perms": {
          "add": "True",
          "change": "True",
          "delete": "True"
        }
      },
      {
        "add_url": "/admin/auth/user/add/",
        "admin_url": "/admin/auth/user/",
        "name": "<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x11057f710>",
        "object_name": "User",
        "perms": {
          "add": "True",
          "change": "True",
          "delete": "True"
        }
      }
    ],
    "name": "<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x108b81850>"
  },
  {
    "app_label": "reservations",
    "app_url": "/admin/reservations/",
    "has_module_perms": "True",
    "models": [
      {
        "add_url": "/admin/reservations/reservationrule/add/",
        "admin_url": "/admin/reservations/reservationrule/",
        "name": "<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x11057f6d0>",
        "object_name": "ReservationRule",
        "perms": {
          "add": "True",
          "change": "True",
          "delete": "True"
        }
      }
    ],
    "name": "Availability"
  },
  {
    "app_label": "blog",
    "app_url": "/admin/blog/",
    "has_module_perms": "True",
    "models": [
      {
        "add_url": "/admin/blog/category/add/",
        "admin_url": "/admin/blog/category/",
        "name": "Categories",
        "object_name": "Category",
        "perms": {
          "add": "True",
          "change": "True",
          "delete": "True"
        }
      },
      {
        "add_url": "/admin/blog/post/add/",
        "admin_url": "/admin/blog/post/",
        "name": "<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x11057f110>",
        "object_name": "Post",
        "perms": {
          "add": "True",
          "change": "True",
          "delete": "True"
        }
      },
      {
        "add_url": "/admin/blog/tag/add/",
        "admin_url": "/admin/blog/tag/",
        "name": "<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x11057f390>",
        "object_name": "Tag",
        "perms": {
          "add": "True",
          "change": "True",
          "delete": "True"
        }
      }
    ],
    "name": "Blog"
  },
(...)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild stab in the dark, but is there any chance that the order in which you call admin.site.register(< Model class >, < ModelAdmin class >) can determine the display order?  Actually, I doubt that would work because I believe Django maintains a registry of the Model -> ModelAdmin objects implemented as a standard Python dictionary, which does not maintain iteration ordering.

If that doesn't behave the way you want, you can always play around with the source in django/contrib/admin.  If you need the iteration order maintained, you could replace the _registry object in the AdminSite class (in admin/sites.py) with a UserDict or DictMixin that maintains insertion order for the keys.  (But please take this advice with a grain of salt, since I've never made these kinds of changes myself and I'm only making an educated guess at how Django iterates over the collection of ModelAdmin objects.  I do think that django/contrib/admin/sites.py is the place to look for this code, though, and the AdminSite class and register() and index() methods in particular are what you want.)

Obviously the nicest thing here would be a simple option for you to specify in your own /admin.py module.  I'm sure that's the kind of answer you were hoping to receive.  I'm not sure if those options exist, though.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to receive that kind of answer and fearing this kind. I think you're right though, at least from what I could find in the docs.

I guess I'll leave this as it is. I don't want to maintain my own version of django.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to make subclasses of django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite and django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin .

I did this so I could display a more descriptive title for each app and order the appearance of models in each app. So I have a dict in my settings.py that maps app_labels to descriptive names and the order in which they should appear, the models are ordered by an ordinal field I provide in each ModelAdmin when I register them with the admin site.

Although making your own subclasses of AdminSite and ModelAdmin is encouraged in the docs, my solution looks like an ugly hack in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Copy `lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\index.html` template to `project1\templates\admin\` directory, where `project1` is the name of your project.

In the copied file, i.e. `project1\templates\admin\index.html`, replace lines:

```
{% block content %} 
...
{% endblock %}
```

with:

```
{% block content %}
<div id="content-main">

{% if app_list %}
    <div class="module">
        <table>
            <caption>App 1</caption>
            <tr>  <th>  <a href="/admin/app1/model1/">Model 1</a>  </th>  <td>Description of model 1</td>  </tr>
            <tr>  <th>  <a href="/admin/app1/model2/">Model 2</a>  </th>  <td>Description of model 1</td>  </tr>
            <tr>  <th>  <a href="..."                >...</a>      </th>  <td>...</td>                     </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="module">
        <table>
            <caption>Authentication and authorization</caption>
            <tr>  <th>  <a href="/admin/auth/user/"  >Users</a>    </th>  <td>List of users</td>           </tr>
            <tr>  <th>  <a href="/admin/auth/group/" >Groups</a>   </th>  <td>List of users' groups</td>   </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <p>{% trans "You don't have permission to view or edit anything." %}</p>
{% endif %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

where:

- `app1`     is the name of your application with models,
- `modeli`   is the name of i-th model in `app1`.

If you defined more than one application with models in your project, then simply add another table in the above `index.html` file.

Because we change the template, we can freely change its HTML code. For example we can add a description of the models as it was shown above. You can also restore *Add* and *Change* links - I deleted them since I think they are redundant.

The answer is a practical demonstration of the solution from [Dave Kasper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/398301).

Answer (score 0):

custom_admin.py

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite


class CustomAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyAdminSite, self).get_urls()
        return urls

    def get_app_list(self, request):
        app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)
        ordered_app_list = []

        if app_dict:
            # TODO: change this dict
            admin_ordering = {
                'app1': ('Model1', 'Model2'),
                'app2': ('Model7', 'Model4'),
                'app3': ('Model3',),
            }

            ordered_app_list = []
            for app_key in admin_ordering:
                app = app_dict[app_key]
                app_ordered_models = []
                for model_name in admin_ordering[app_key]:
                    for model in app_dict[app_key]['models']:
                        if model['object_name'] == model_name:
                            app_ordered_models.append(model)
                            break

                app['models'] = app_ordered_models
                ordered_app_list.append(app)

        return ordered_app_list
```

admin_site = CustomAdminSite()

urls.py

```
from custom_admin import admin_site

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin_site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to your settings.py:

```
def get_app_list(self, request):
    """
    Return a sorted list of all the installed apps that have been
    registered on this site.
    """
    ordering = {
        # for superuser
        'Group': 1,
        'User': 2,

        # fist app
        'TopMessage': 101,
        'Slider': 102,
        'ProductCategory': 103,
        'Product': 104,
        'ProductPicture': 105,
        
        # 2nd app
        'ProductReview': 201,
        'Promotion': 202,
        'BestSeller': 203,
    }
    app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)
    app_list = sorted(app_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x['name'].lower())

    for app in app_list:
        app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: ordering[x['object_name']])

    return app_list


admin.AdminSite.get_app_list = get_app_list
```

And make changes to the ordering dictionary to match your apps and models. That's it.

The benefit of my solution is that it will show the 'auth' models if the user is a superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Django, by default, orders the models in admin alphabetically. So the order of models in Event admin is Epic, EventHero, EventVillain, Event

Instead you want the order to be

- EventHero, EventVillain, Epic then event.

The template used to render the admin index page is `admin/index.html` and the view function is `ModelAdmin.index`.

```
def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
"""
Display the main admin index page, which lists all of the installed
apps that have been registered in this site.
"""
app_list = self.get_app_list(request)
context = {
    **self.each_context(request),
    'title': self.index_title,
    'app_list': app_list,
    **(extra_context or {}),
}

request.current_app = self.name

return TemplateResponse(request, self.index_template or
    'admin/index.html', context)
```

The method `get_app_list`, set the order of the models.:

```
def get_app_list(self, request):
"""
Return a sorted list of all the installed apps that have been
registered in this site.
"""
app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)

# Sort the apps alphabetically.
app_list = sorted(app_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x['name'].lower())

# Sort the models alphabetically within each app.
for app in app_list:
    app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])

return app_list
```

So to set the order we override `get_app_list` as:

```
class EventAdminSite(AdminSite):
def get_app_list(self, request):
    """
    Return a sorted list of all the installed apps that have been
    registered in this site.
    """
    ordering = {
        "Event heros": 1,
        "Event villains": 2,
        "Epics": 3,
        "Events": 4
    }
    app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)
    # a.sort(key=lambda x: b.index(x[0]))
    # Sort the apps alphabetically.
    app_list = sorted(app_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x['name'].lower())

    # Sort the models alphabetically within each app.
    for app in app_list:
        app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: ordering[x['name']])

    return app_list
```

The code `app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: ordering[x['name']])` sets the fixed ordering. Your app now looks like this.

[image]

[Check the Documentation](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/set_ordering.html)

Answer (score 0):

In `Settings.py` file setting the order in which the apps/modules show up listed on Admin

set my ordering list

```
ADMIN_ORDERING = [
    ('Your_App1', '*'),
    ('Your_App2', '*'),
]
```

Creating a sort function below ADMIN_ORDERING

```
def get_app_list(self, request):
    """
    You Can Set Manually Ordering For Your Apps And Models   

        ADMIN_ORDERING = [
            ('Your_App1', [
                'module_1',
                'module_2'
            ]),
            ('Your_App2', '*'),
        ]
    """

    app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)

    # Let's start by sorting the apps alphabetically on a list:
    app_list = sorted(app_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x['name'].lower())

    # Sorting the models alphabetically within each app.
    for app in app_list:
        if app['app_label'] in [el[0] for el in ADMIN_ORDERING]:
            app_list.remove(app)
        else:
            app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])

    # Now we order the app list in our defined way in ADMIN_ORDERING (which could be a subset of all apps).
    my_ordered_apps = []
    if app_dict:
        for app_name, object_list in ADMIN_ORDERING:
            app = app_dict[app_name]
            if object_list == '*':
                app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])
            else:
                app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: object_list.index(x['object_name']))
            my_ordered_apps.append(app)

        # Now we combine and arrange the 2 lists together
        my_ordered_apps.extend(app_list)

    return my_ordered_apps

# Covering django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.get_app_list
from django.contrib import admin
admin.AdminSite.get_app_list = get_app_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a simple and self contained approach can be using the decorator pattern to resort your app and modules in this way:

```
# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin

def app_resort(func):                                                                                            
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):                                                                                            
        app_list = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # Useful to discover your app and module list:
        #import pprint                                                                                          
        #pprint.pprint(app_list)

        app_sort_key = 'name'
        app_ordering = {
            "APP_NAME1": 1,
            "APP_NAME2": 2,
            "APP_NAME3": 3,
        }

        resorted_app_list = sorted(app_list, key=lambda x: app_ordering[x[app_sort_key]] if x[app_sort_key] in app_ordering else 1000)

        model_sort_key = 'object_name'
        model_ordering = {
            "Model1": 1,
            "Model2": 2,
            "Model3": 3,
            "Model14": 4,
        }
        for app in resorted_app_list:
            app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: model_ordering[x[model_sort_key]] if x[model_sort_key] in model_ordering else 1000)
        return resorted_app_list
    return inner                                                                                            
                   
admin.site.get_app_list = app_resort(admin.site.get_app_list)
```

This code sorts at the top only the defined keys in the ordering dict, leaving at the bottom all the other.
The approach is clean but it requires get_app_list to be executed before... which is probably not a good idea when performance is important and you have a large app_list.

Answer (score 0):

### At least, there are 3 ways to do model ordering in Django admin panel:

---

> By changing `verbose_name_plural` in **Meta** class of model

*not bad way, but you will see numbers in admin panel*

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "2. A"

class B(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "1. B"
```

---

> By using third-party library [`django-modeladmin-reorder`](https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder)

*it is simple and fast, but **not django-clean** as well as this library is very old and abandoned*

---

> By overriding the default admin site method `get_app_list`

***django-clean** method, but more time expenses to configure*

```
# First of - override the default admin site
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-default-admin-site
# Note that it is project files, not application files!!!

#myproject/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    ...

#myproject/apps.py
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig

class MyAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = "myproject.admin.MyAdminSite"

#myproject/settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    #'django.contrib.admin', remove this!
    'myproject.apps.MyAdminConfig',# replaces 'django.contrib.admin'
    ...
]

# The second step - overriding a method

#myproject/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from my_app.models import A, B, C# import your models from application

class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    def get_app_list(self, request, app_label=None):
        order = [B, A]# place there your first models in order, remaining ones will be after them
        app_list = admin.AdminSite.get_app_list(self, request)
        for app in app_list:
            if app.get('app_label') == 'my_app':# your app's name in apps.py of application
                app["models"].sort(key=lambda x: order.index(x['model']) if x['model'] in order else len(order))

        return app_lis
```

Answer (score -1):

This has [become a lot easier](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/4.1/#django-contrib-admin) in Django 4.1:

> The `AdminSite.get_app_list()` method now allows changing the order of apps and models on the admin index page.

You can subclass and override [this method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.get_app_list) to change the order the returned list of apps/models.

Comment: could you show how to use it I'm a beginner