# How can I change the order of my models on the admin index page?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In Django, I have not found a way to reorder the order my models appear in the application listing in the administration panel. I've seen [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398163/ordering-admin-modeladmin-objects-in-django-admin) on SO that link to a [djangosnippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2613/). Unfortunately, this snippet doesn't seem to work in 1.5. There is a seven year old [feature request](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3591) regarding this issue.

Is there a way, that works in 1.5, to specify application model order on the Django admin? I'd like to be able to order by model as indicated by the numbers in the image, opposed to the default alphabetical.

[image: Proposed ordering]

Comment: I'm sure you could do it, but it's some very heavy lifting. You'd be better off just making your own admin if you need that level of customization.

Comment: In the github code for django, there is django/contrib/admin/sites.py, which has a function named app_index(), which has a line that sorts the models ... `app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])`.  Maybe you could add another attribute to your models, and make sure that gets included in the app['models'] dictionaries and then change the sorting line to use that attribute.

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/rhec/rheclib/blob/master/rheclib/templatetags/admin_app_order.py

Comment: @Jingo, that does the apps themselves, not the models within the apps.

Comment: @Andy oh, sry, I did not pay enought attention to your question...